# complex cell that are higher than screen in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, uitableview

Hi I am using uitableview in my app where the cells contain images, comments, buttons. The cell are different sizes and the content is very dynamic. Much like what you see in the instagram feed.

My problem is that since the cells is often higher than the screen itself and also have a complex content that need to bee updated the scrolling become a bit laggy. Of course I use threads to load images etc.

I have tested alot with different approached but didn't find a good solution yet. Is it possible to ovverride UItableview so it does not forget the cell when it dissappear from view but maybe at a certain content-position ... and still keep the memory advantages of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Comment: Are you caching any content that is downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

If your rows are all so unique and costly to construct, you could create and manage your "row" views manually in a UIScrollView, then you have full control over when you alloc, cache, and release your row views.    You can adjust your caching to account for scroll speed, scroll direction, # of rows in the table, # of rows in the scroll direction, etc., anything and everything you can think of to get your scrolling smooth.   Of course you lose some of the convenience of the UITableView, but that's a trade-off you have to make sometimes.